# Switch statement is not taking the input

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

What is wrong with this code? The switch statement is not taking the input. If I declare the value of variable 'a' directly then it is showing the output.

```
var a = prompt("value");
console.log(fun(a));
function fun(value)
 {
    let ans = "";
    switch(value)
      {
          case 1:
            ans = "alpha";
            break;
          case 2:
            ans = "beta";
            break;
          case 3:
            ans = "gamma";
            break;
      }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: a string is not a number.

Comment: `var a = Number(prompt("value"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` uses strict equality (===) to match `Switch` expression to `case` clauses.

In your code, `value` is a string but your `case` clauses are numbers, so because of strict equality, string `value` won't be coerced to match the `case` clauses which are numbers.

You can convert the result of `prompt` to a number before passing it to the function.

Change

```
var a = prompt("value");
```

to

```
var a = Number(prompt("value"));
```

Comment: @Tushar i appreciate you editing the answer but please don't add more content to the answer without the permission of the person who posted the answer.

Comment: Apologies I am new. I was of the impression you will get the request for edit.

Comment: No worries. You can add your edit as a comment.

Comment: @TusharShahi, no you get informed when your _after_ the answer has been edited. People who submit answers here have a specific reason to communicate the way they do, and, while I don't mind being corrected if I'm wrong on something in comments, it doesn't help if someone's editing my answer like they know better. Like Yousaf said it's no problem, but just be mindful going foward.

Comment: @TusharShahi after [2k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), the edit is applied immediately without a review process

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing integers with string, just add quotes to cases

```js
var a = prompt("value");
console.log(fun(a));
function fun(value)
 {
    let ans = "";
    switch(value)
      {
          case "1":
            ans = "alpha";
            break;
          case "2":
            ans = "beta";
            break;
          case "3":
            ans = "gamma";
            break;
      }
   return ans;
}
```